# Overlaying greyscale color channels

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I want to overlay two or more color channels to visualize co-localization. I've played around with matplotlib's `imshow` and what I've gotten so far is this:

[image]

So the overlap is already pretty obvious, albeit with the caveat that I have to set the alpha of one channel lower, to actually see which spot belongs to which color. But it seems like this method creates a not-so-clear picture.

Is there a smarter way?

[images here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/162bf8c6ae4f386098a693eca0dce12520180504093056/45bbac)

```
import matplotlib.colors
import skimage.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

green_c = skimage.io.imread("c1.tif")
red_c   = skimage.io.imread("c2.tif")

cmap_grn = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "green"])
cmap_red   = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "red"])

cmap_grn.set_under("k", 0)
cmap_red.set_under("k", 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 3, figsize = (10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()

greenlim = [2e3, 3e3]
redlim = [2e3, 4e3]

ax[0].imshow(green_c, clim = greenlim, cmap = cmap_grn, alpha = 1)

ax[1].imshow(red_c, clim = redlim, cmap = cmap_red, alpha = 1)

ax[2].imshow(red_c, clim = redlim, cmap = cmap_red, alpha = 1)
ax[2].imshow(green_c, clim = greenlim, cmap = cmap_grn, alpha = 0.5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it make sense for your data to quantize it to few levels first? Also, I'd try to invert the source images as the overlapping should be more clear on a white background.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking at the difference between the images? 
I don't know in how far this makes sense for the practical application but to get a visual of the differences it might make sense.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.colors
import skimage.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

green_c = skimage.io.imread("../data/c1.tif")
red_c   = skimage.io.imread("../data/c2.tif")

cmap_grn = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "green"])
cmap_red   = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "red"])
cmap_diff   = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red", "white", "green"])

cmap_grn.set_under("k", 0)
cmap_red.set_under("k", 0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 3, figsize = (10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()

greenlim = [2e3, 3e3]
redlim = [2e3, 4e3]

green_norm = (green_c-greenlim[0])/np.diff(greenlim)
red_norm = (red_c-redlim[0])/np.diff(redlim)

diff = green_norm - red_norm
difflim = np.max(np.abs(diff))
difflim = [-difflim, +difflim]

ax[0].imshow(green_norm, clim=[0,1], cmap = cmap_grn, alpha = 1)

ax[1].imshow(red_norm, clim=[0,1], cmap = cmap_red, alpha = 1)

im_diff = ax[2].imshow(diff, clim = [-2,2], cmap = cmap_diff)

plt.tight_layout()
cax = fig.add_axes([1,.2,.025,.6])
fig. colorbar(im_diff, ax=ax[2], cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with the normalization, the way ImportanceOfBeingErnest did in their example, and from there it was very easy to do some real color blending of the two images without resorting to some hacky canvas buffer tricks that I've seen around here.

I realize some of the adjustment steps may be redundant, so there's some playing around to be done.

(I tried with white background also. While it works well for single channels, it looks a bit... weird for the blended result in this particular case.)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.colors
import skimage.io
import skimage.exposure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rescale_intensity(image, p1 = 0, p2 = 100):
    if p1 and p2 not in range(101):
        raise TypeError

    p1, p2 = np.percentile(image, [p1, p2])
    img_rescale = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(image, in_range = (p1, p2))
    return img_rescale

green_c = skimage.io.imread("c1.tif")
red_c   = skimage.io.imread("c2.tif")

cmap_grn   = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "green"])
cmap_red   = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["black", "red"])

greenlim = [2e3, 5e3]
redlim = [2e3, 5e3]

green_norm = (green_c-greenlim[0])/np.diff(greenlim)
red_norm = (red_c-redlim[0])/np.diff(redlim)

green_rgba = cmap_grn(green_norm)
red_rgba   = cmap_red(red_norm)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 4, figsize = (10,5))
ax = ax.ravel()

blend = np.maximum(green_rgba, red_rgba)

ax[0].imshow(green_rgba)
ax[1].imshow(red_rgba)
ax[2].imshow(blend)
ax[3].imshow(rescale_intensity(blend, 50, 80))

titles = ["Green", "Red", "Blended", "Blended Adjusted"]

for a, t in zip(ax, titles):
    a.set_title(t)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```